# .htaccess RewriteRule error in a CGI script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following files:

```
website-folder
  - .htaccess
  - user.php
```

the .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]{1,11})$user.php?user_id=$1
```

Now I want to give in `localhost/website-folder/user/1234` which should take the data from `localhost/website-folder/user.php?user_id=1234`.

But I am getting following error:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/website-folder/.htaccess` file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Set the base from which to rewrite as the site runs from a subfolder.
# This can be safely removed if you ever move to the root of the domain
RewriteBase /website-folder/

# Rewrite user/{id} to user.php (skip existing files)
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]{1,11})$ user.php?user_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The error was thrown as you had a code formatting issue (assuming you copy-pasted the code into your question): there was no space between `$` and `user.php...`.

I've also added a `RewriteBase` in your file as you are running from a sub-folder.

Lastly, I've added the Query String Append (`QSA`) flag, which allows you to add more query parameters to the rewritten URI. You also left out the Last flag (`L`), which would have introduced potential issues for other rules below it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. However, that may not help you as I doubt your assets follow the same naming. Where are your assets stored?